# Simplest approach for 301 for small website moved to Wordpress

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

**Scenario**

I'm moderating a website that has moved to a Wordpress based setup, but without access to all the administration tools in Wordpress (it's externally hosted/managed), but I do have access to the htaccess file. Now, there's two things I need to do:

1. Redirect the old pages to the new url structure.
2. Redirect all www calls to non-www.

**The challenge**

I would however like to accomplish this with:

1. Fewest possible redirects per call (preferably only 1).
2. With limited rule duplication.
3. Be somewhat readable (not just one inline Regex handling it all).
4. All edited in the htaccess alone.

What is giving me a hard time, is keeping the redirects to a minimum when it is both an old url, and prefixed with www as well.

My next biggest problem is, that I would like to use a rewrite map, but it seems you have to load something externally, rather than defining a dictionary in the htaccess file which is what I would prefer.

**Further details**

- I'm no expert at using the Rewrite Engine so I might be missing a simple solution here.
- The old website was structured simply with `/index.php?page=<pageName>`.
- The new website uses seo-friendly urls `/a-new-url-example/`.
- Two examples could be:

  1. from `mydomain.com/index.php?page=boots` to `mydomain.com/boots/`
  2. from `www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=shoes` to `mydomain.com/shiny-shoes/` *(some kind of map is needed to handle `shoes`->`shiny-shoes`)*
- The current setup on my own computer does not allow me to test it locally (having a lot of conflicts with other projects), so currently I am testing the setup with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.
- [Current content of the htaccess file](http://pastebin.com/skbzc3g5) (on pastebin, as the code kept getting interpreted as something else here).

Comment: Please give some examples of old and new urls. The one-redirect is possible if you do the www to no-www redirect last.

Comment: @Gerben: I did not notice I screwed up the formatting, my bad (`<pageName>`) was parsed away), but I have updated it now and added two examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this doesn't clash with your existing rules inside htaccess, as you have provided that.

```
#exceptions first
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shoes3$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /shiny-shoes/? [R=302]

#urls that directly map to the new url scheme
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/? [R=302]

#note the absence of the L flag in the above rules.
# from apache docs: the [R] flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset

# no-www (make sure this is the last rule)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://[^/]+/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I also tried the QUERY_STRING approach, but it seems that, if http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ are to be believed, will result in reuse of the old querystring (`?page=shoes`) which I am not interested in. It might be because of a missing setting though. As for existing rules, there is only a catch all in the end that makes index.php handle all incoming calls.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to put a `?` at the end of the rewritten url. As for the existing rules. As long as they don't internally rewrite to `index.php?page=...` you won't have any trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly? It still adds `?page=shoes`, and furthermore, it does not remove the `www.` prefix ("Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. A redirect will be made with status code 301").

Comment: See edit above. I added the line from the apache docs that explains that [R] doesn't mean apache will redirect immediately, not without the [L] flag. I however didn't account for the hostname being present in the url. The above code should work now. I tested it on my server. Remember to change 302 to 301 once it is working.

Comment: I guess I'd better create a virtual machine or something like that, so I'm able to test it properly. What about the querystring is that removed in your test? Because on the test site I get the following result when testing example 2: `http://www.mydomain.com/shiny-shoes/?page=shoes`. If not fully there, you got me the most of the way though. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes, that should be fixed. The old code used 301 redirect, and those are cached by your browser, so clear you browsers cache first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

**Conditions:**

.1 .htaccess file with these rules is at the root directory.

.2 The GET value ("value" in the example below) is not modified in the requested URL. In other words, "shoes" is the same in the requested URL, not "shiny-shoes" as in the question. It is posible, but would require a list of alias to be included in the pattern, or a diferent rule for each item.

.3 The index.php script in the root directory must be able to handle all possible values and load the normal page, if any, when no match is found.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    #Redirect from http://www.mydomain.com to http://mydomain.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    #mydomain.com/value/ to  mydomain.com/index.php?page=value
    RewriteRule ^(.*)?/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

To test this example, include the following only code at index.php in root directory:

```
    <?php
    if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'value' ) { // Change "value" accordingly 
      echo "Processing item <br /><br />";
    }
    else {
      echo "Loading normal page<br /><br />";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If I understand your solution correctly, then it will redirect from www to non-www and then test if the url is of the correct format and do yet another redirect if it does not, is that correct? Because that is what I am trying to avoid. Also, the "shiny-shoes" thing was on purpose, and I was wondering how it should be solved. There are not that many entries, so a rule for each item is possible, but I would rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: @Johny: Both rules are independent. The first one removes `www` from the URL. The last one checks if the pattern matches the entered URL. If it does, replaces **/value/** with **/index.php?page=value** in the URL. The browser address bar will keep showing the entered URL, which, of course, should be the friendly version. That's what the rewriting rules are for, I guess.

Comment: I just added my "test setup" to the description which might be my problem to begin with, because it might be giving me a wrong result, but it does seem to be the most recommended service for testing htaccess redirects. When using your approach with the service it returns after the www/non-www part. Are there bugs in that test?

Comment: Try with trailing slash always, like in your example: **mydomain.com/value/**. That requirement can be removed easily in case your example was not literal. I will modify the regex if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Where should I always try with that? I tested the setup against both of my examples, and neither of them worked? The second example do get redirected to a non-www version though, but still not with the new url structure.